# How to do a hanging indent when other content is present

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that is a variation on getting a hanging indent to work.

I have searched on getting a hanging indent to work, the common solution is to set a padding of *x* px and a text-indent of *-x* px.

I can get this to work on its own, however if the span is in a container with a link, it causes the span to be shifted down a line.

Markup code:

```
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td class="first">
      <a href="#">888.555-222</a>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex sed ornatus appetere. Modus consequat ut sed. Mel ne sumo dico possim, duo an doming albucius gubergren, mea posse quodsi id. Usu </span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td.first {
  width: 30%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 60px;
  text-indent: -60px;
}
```

Here is a simple js fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/spm4xqw5/  I want the span to be on the same line as the link, but if the text wraps then I want the subsequent lines to be indented.

Comment: And I take it you cannot simply place the link/anchor within the span? (_I.e., something like `<span><a href="#">Whatever</a> Your text that will indent...</span>`_)

Comment: hm yes I am able to place the entire contents of the table cell in a span, if that will help provide a solution

Comment: Oh, well then in that case, perhaps something like the following would suffice: https://jsfiddle.net/3w16yqt2/1/ (Note, in that case, I have an additional span between the anchor tag and text, which exists to provide some space between the two. The amount of space can be adjusted in the CSS by modifying the width.) Not 100% if that's what you're looking for, though; hence why I sent this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but if you need two inline-blocks side by side in a container of limited width, all you need to do is set the width of both inline-blocks explicitly.
So with an `a` of 60px and a `td` of 30%, the `span` needs to be `30%-60px` wide.
No need for text-indent or padding. The boxes are of different height, so I added a `vertical-align` for good measure.

```css
td.first {
  width: 30%;
}


a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  /*
  padding-left: 60px;
  text-indent: -60px;
  */
  width:calc(30% - 60px);
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">
      <p>
        <a href="#">888.555-222</a>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ex sed ornatus appetere. Modus consequat ut sed. Mel ne sumo dico possim, duo an doming albucius gubergren, mea posse quodsi id. Usu </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the reason why I'm not sure this is what you want, is that the contents of the `a` are wider than 60px, so they overflow out of the `a` into the `span`. Nothing fatal though, I hope.

Comment: In my particular case, the link will always be fixed width, but the span text will be variable.  I'm not too terribly advanced with css and did not know about calculating values, much less subtracting a fixed width from a percentage-based on.  This is exactly what I was looking for, many thanks